# aspnet core app strange request type

Tags: php, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am building a asp.net core app with the debfault aspnetidentitycore plugedin, the only change is i added an action by modified the regiester method to a api, which means can be called by another app.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<EngineResult<object>> RegisterByApi([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                DisplayName = model.Name,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return new EngineResult<object>(true) { Entity = new { sub = user.Id, name = user.DisplayName } };
            }
            return new EngineResult<object>(false) { Entity = string.Join(";", result.Errors?.Select(e => e.Description)) };
        }

        return new EngineResult<object>(false) { Entity = string.Join(";", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)) };
    }
```

but when a php calls this api, i get a strange content-type, which is 
**application/json; boundary=------------------------e3f0ef0cc3e74f25**

here is the php code

```
<?php
$data = [
    "Name"=>"testname",
    "Email"=>"123@testdomain.com",
    "Password"=>"123qwe!#QWE",
    "ConfirmPassword"=>"123qwe!@#QWE",
    "PhoneNumber"=>"12312321321",
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxx/Account/RegisterByApi"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
header_remove(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, it is a my php code issue, that not use a json data, replace the post data with a convert to josn will resolve this issue:
$payload = json_encode($data);